# Is there any way to create the distinction between time slowing down and clocks slowing down?

Tags: special-relativity, time, time-dilation, observers

As Einstein once said, "Time is what you measure with a clock".

So my question is: is there any way to create the distinction between time slowing down and clocks slowing down because of other factors such as velocity or change in distances affecting the frequency of oscillations?

Comment: No. That would not be mainstream physics.

Comment: true, but it would still be physics

Comment: Yes. But, as you are aware, being about non-mainstream physics is a *closure reason* for questions on this site.

Comment: As you say, clocks measure time So if time slows, so do the clocks that measure it. Are you asking if these are distinct ways of slowing time and clocks? 1) Moving frame of reference. 2) Acceleration/Gravitational field. 3) Expansion of the universe causing a red shift.

Answer (score 4):

> is there any way to create the distinction between time slowing down and clocks slowing down because of other factors such as velocity or change in distances affecting the frequency of oscillations?

No. At least, not in a scientific sense. Philosophically you can do whatever.

If time slows down then the measurable effect is that all clocks slow down by the same amount. If all clocks slow down by the same amount due to some other reason then that other reason is scientifically indistinguishable from time slowing down. So by the principle of the identity of indistinguishables that other reason is therefore the same thing as time slowing down.

Comment: Imo if time did not slow down, it would be possible that all clocks would not slow down by the same amount, depending on the exact mechanism of the clock. If time did slow down, there would be no difference, as you said. Afaik the first possibility is not really contradicted by observations

Comment: @Neelim “Afaik the first possibility is not really contradicted by observations” Yes it is. Time dilation occurs for clocks based on gravity, electromagnetism, the weak force, and the strong force, and all the same.

Comment: I did not actually say that time dilation does not happen. What I meant is that time does not actually slow down, it is just the appearance of time that slows down between moving reference frames. And the mechanism of the clock *could* affect the *perceived* time dilation that is empirically measured. The effect would be be very small when using an atomic clock

Comment: @Neelim as you are well aware, comments are not for conversation here on PSE. I suggest you read about the identity of indiscernables

Answer (score 2):

No.

> As Einstein once said, "Time is what you measure with a clock".

It follows that time does not slow down because clocks do not slow down. A clock measures time at the rate of one second per second. This is not subject to change. Relativity does not talk of time slowing down, but of the *appearance* of time slowing down. It *appears* to one observer that the time of another observer has slowed down. This is not to do with any physical effect altering the frequency of oscillations, but depends only on the way an observer makes a comparison between his clock and the clock of another observer.

Comment: so it can be said that time doesn't slow down, it is the perception of time that slows down. That is actually how I thought about it. In that case wouldn't it mean that one second measured by a clock stationery relative to me, would appear to give a different one second compared to a clock that is moving relative to me? So all clocks aren't measuring at one second per second?

Comment: All clocks measure at one second per second, but time is a local quantity. It is strictly only meaningful in the immediate vicinity of the clock which measures it. This is true also of time as we experience it. It is only meaningful in our immediate environment. The time measured by a different clock, in a different place or moving differently, is a different quantity.

Comment: I'm sure we agree about the substance of what you're saying, but I'd like to suggest a better wording.   The North Pole is straight ahead of me.  I turn 90 degrees.  Now the North Pole is to my right.  Did the North Pole's location change?  Of course not.  Did my *perception* of its location change?  Once again, I'd say certainly not.  What changed was my *description* of its location, not my perception.  Likewise with time dilation.  When I change velocity, I assign new times to various events and the intervals between them.  That's not a change in perception; it's a change in description.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there are two different ideas in your question.

First, time slowing down and clocks slowing down within that frame are the same thing.  For me, this is most easily comprehended by considering natural clocks such as the oscillation frequency of a cesium atom.  Special relativity predicts that time will slow (the cesium atom will oscillate slower) with relativistic speeds.  General relativity also predicts that time will slow in the presence of gravity.  If you are in the same frame as the cesium atom that you want to evaluate, you will percieve no change; your reference cesium atomic clock will oscillate (count ticks of time) at exactly the same rate as the cesium clock that you are evaluating next to you.  *Everything* in that frame with you, including all natural phenomena, slows down together.  An observer in another reference frame can observe those relativistic effects of time slowing by comparing your distant clock ticks with clock ticks in their own reference frame.

The second idea in your question I think is related to classic Doppler shift, where the signal from each clock tick will need to travel a further distance (if the clock is moving away).  The slowed rate of received clock pulses from this classic Doppler effect is due to the increased distance that each subsequent clock pulse needs to travel to get to the observer.  This slowed rate is due to distance, not because of time slowing for the sending clock.

When receiving signals from distant objects, both effects are combined, meaning that the received frequency rate will be a combination of classical and relativistic Doppler effects.  However if the relative speed of that distant object is *known*, then the classical Doppler shift can be calculated out as as separate artifact, since that increased distance traveled between each clock pulse can be determined and accounted for.  This allows then for separation of the two effects, but only if there is a separate independent way to determine (or estimate) the relative speed between observer and moving clock.

Answer (score 0):

> "Time is what you measure with a clock"

If you take this literally then there is no difference between time and what a clock measures, so the short answer is no.

It feels a little bit like a meaningless definition but if you think about it, it's actually hard to create a better one.

The reason for this is that Time is the movement of things around us.  So a gas diffusing into another gas is just the combined movement of all the atoms, a ball falling is just all the atoms of the balling moving together and someone aging is a complicated combination of a large group of atoms that form cells that move, vibrate and interact with each other (to simply things drastically), but in essence aging is just motion.

Clocks are also just motion, whether it's the mechanical hand of a wind up clock ticking, electrons flowing in an electrical clock or the natural frequency of a cesium atom in an atomic clock.  A clock is just a regular repeating motion to compare against other motion.

So we're using regular repeating motion (a clock) to measure other motion.  Hence a clock can be used to measure time.

It can get confusing when considering relativistic speeds (e.g. Relativity).  This is shown most simply with Einsteins light clock in a train thought experiment.  A stationary observer outside the train sees that the light has to travel in a triangle and hence a longer distance.  Given that the speed of light is fixed, it must take longer to travel this further distance.  Hence one cycle of the clock on the train will take longer than one cycle of the same clock in a stationary frame.

Einstein was smart enough to realise that this applies to everything on the train, not just the light clock.  This can best be shown by considering a thought experiment where the train is travelling at the maximum limit, e.g. the speed of light.  At this speed everything on the train is travelling at the speed of light in one direction.  We can see that the light in the light clock can no longer go up and down (or else it would be going faster than the speed of light).  We can imagine atoms in a gas vibrating and realise they also cannot vibrate (or they would be going faster than the speed of light at some point), similarly electrons cannot move around the nucleus (as they are already travelling at the speed of light in one direction).  In essence there can be no movement other than in the direction of travel, e.g. time appears to have frozen.

Matter cannot however travel at the speed of light (although it is useful to consider as a limit).  If we consider the train travelling at 99% the speed of light we see a similar thing, the light clock can only move slowly as most of it's motion is in the direction of travel, the same goes for electrons, atoms, molecules, cells, etc, *they are limited in their speed relative to the frame of reference* as they are already going 99% c in one direction.

Put simply the speed of a frame of reference effects motion within that frame.  In essence it slows it down relative to the frame of reference.  Given time is motion then a fast moving frame of reference will experience a slow down of motion or a slow down of time (relative to that frame).  This slow down is not noticeable from within the frame of reference as any means of measuring it is also slowed down.

**In summary (and simplifying a little):**

Time is motion.

A clock is just a regular repeating motion.

Motion (and therefore time) are effected (slowed down) by the speed of your frame of reference (as shown by Einsteins light clock in a train experiment).

As per it's title (Relativity), time is relative to the frame of reference you are in.  You may ask is there an absolute time (for all frames of references)?  If there is, we currently we don't have any way of measuring it, so it becomes more a philosophical point than a real thing.

And to return to your question, all clocks are based on motion of some kind, all motion is slowed down equally relative to a frame of references speed, therefore you will not notice  any difference between any clock due to the frame of references speed or any difference between any other aspect or measure of time.